# Creating Custom UITableViewCell in Swift Programmatically

Tags: uitableview

I need a cell with a label that takes up the entire contentView. I've done this a bunch of times with a nib but this time I decided to avoid the creating a nib. Below is my code.

```
class StackLegendCell: UITableViewCell {

  var title = UILabel()

  override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    contentView.addSubview(title)

    title.numberOfLines = 1
    title.textAlignment = .center
    title.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(1000, for: .horizontal)
    title.setContentHuggingPriority(1000, for: .horizontal)
    title.text = "??"
    //contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    title.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
    title.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0).isActive = true
  }
```

The problem is that the label doesn't show anything. A check into view debugger shows that width = height = 0. But I'm setting height and width anchors which should give a size to be the same as the contentView.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Try add `contentView.addSubview(title)` this code to last position of this method.

Comment: That will not work. In fact, it causes a crash because there has to be an existing relation when setting the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. You missed setting the frame of the titleLabel

`title.frame = contentView.frame`

add this line of code and build. This should work.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think that will work either. Doesn't that essentially hard-code the frame size? How will my constraints take effect if the frame is hard-coded?

Comment: I already tested with your code and it works fine. First, you need to show title on table view cell and then you need to think about constraints.

Comment: I double checked the results after assigning the label's frame from the contentView and really doesn't work. This particular table (& cell) is positioned 40 points for the right margin. I inspected the label in the view Debugger and it shows a width much larger than the 40 points (which is what I was expecting to see). The width is 320 points. The height is fine. In fact, the label only shows if the text alignments is .left. It's off the screen for center and right, So, we (or at least I'm) missing something ...